# running xUnit from command line on Build Server (TeamCity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, xunit.net

I have a .net Core web app that uses xunit for testing.

This web app has COM dll references. Currently the dotnet CLI does not support COM references. So, I **cannot run** `dotnet test`. *(If I do, I get the error:  error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core...)*

A workaround is to use the xunit console runner: [here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#run-tests).

The problem is that the xunit.console.exe is in the nuget package folder which seems to be only at *%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.console\2.2.0\tools*

I need to access this xunit.console.exe on the build server, so I do not want to use %USERPROFILE%.

Is there some standard place I can/should put this exe so I can access it on the build server?

Comment: How about using `dotnet xunit`? It uses the xUnit console behind the hoods and would allow you not to have to deal with finding the `.exe`. Here's the docs related to how to use it: https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html#create-project

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey Good try, but no luck. Same ResolveComReference error. 
I guess for now, i'll just use %USERPROFILE%...the exe will just be located in the build agent user's directory.